# Hypothesis Testing- comparing z crit and score

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am learning some basic hypothesis testing for single population.

Lets say:

$H_0$: $\le$ 5

$H_a$: > 5

I have a Z crit of -1.65 and a calculated Z score of -.72

How would I determine to whether to accept or reject the null hypothesis without looking at the p values but only comparing the z score and z crit?